# Access a static variable from a class stored in a variable

Tags: php, class

Given a class:

```
class SomeClass{
     static $information = 'useful information';
}
```

I a trying to access a static variable in a set of php classes. Each class has the $information static variable. If I access the static variable directly

```
echo SomeClass::$information;
```

The program outputs the information, however if I try to access it storing it in a variable I get a error that the '::' is unexpected.

```
$class = SomeClass;
echo $class::$information;
```

The reason for storing the class in a variable is so that I can have a function that can create an array of Users or an array of Projects for example.

Comment: Why would you need to store the class in a variable? What would that gain you.

Comment: https://eval.in/594385

Comment: Writing a static function `static function getInformation(){return $self::$information;}` because the '::' is unexpected.

nor does `static function getInformation{return $self->$information;}` because $self is non-object.

Comment: A function that can create instances of more than one type of class. For example create an array of Users or an array of Projects

Comment: I think the problem is routed in the fact I'm using a server with PHP 5.3 so I'm migrating the project to see if that fixes the problem and allows these solutions to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SomeClass {
  public static $information = 'useful information';

  public static function getInformation() {
    return self::$information;
  }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
# Static Access
echo SomeClass::$information;
echo SomeClass::getInformation();

# Static Access via Class Name in Variable
$someClass = 'SomeClass';
echo $someClass::$information;

## Instantiated access
$someClass = new SomeClass();
echo $someClass->$information;
echo $someClass->getInformation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$class = SomeClass::class;
echo $class::$information;
```

`::class` gets the fully qualified name of a class as a string.

Comment: What version of PHP is that for?

Comment: @user1320619 PHP 5.5, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a reference to class in a variable, it is useless.

Instead you can store the class name in a variable and call the static method or variable:

```
$class = 'SomeClass';
echo $class::$information;
```